# Holt Winters forecast in R

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I want to make a [prediction](/questions/tagged/prediction) with `Holt Winters`, but I make some kind of mistake.

From my dataset, which contains some 10k values, I only want those that are outside the given range 15-26.
All values per week that fall outside the range I put into the data frame "out". Starting from 2nd January week 2020.

So far so good.

I have one value per week and would like to make a prediction with Holt Winters about the increase in the following weeks. But my plot looks very incomprehensible. There is no forecast to see. What am I doing wrong?

```
df_B2 = fread("C:/Users/B2.csv")
df_B2$Date = as.Date(df_B2$Date, "%d.%m.%y")
df_B2$Week = strftime(df_B2$Date, format = "%V")

#Limit
limit_a = 15
limit_b = 26`

out = (df_B2 %>% filter(ExtractionTimes < limit_a | ExtractionTimes > limit_b) %>% count(Week))

 str(out)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Week: chr  "02" "03" "04" "05"
 $ n   : int  99 106 156 237
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

out
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Week      n
  <chr> <int>
1 02       99
2 03      106
3 04      156
4 05      237

data = ts(out$n,start=c(2020,02), frequency = 52)

hw = HoltWinters(data, alpha=NULL, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
> p = predict (hw, n.ahead=1, level=0.95)
> plot(hw,p)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stats::plot.HoltWinters()` function is showing you the data (in black) and fitted values and forecasts (in red).

Since you are already using tidyverse packages, you will probably find it easier to use the `tsibble` and `fable` packages which fit the same model in a tidy framework.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(tsibble, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(fable, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
#> Loading required package: fabletools

out <- tibble(
    Week = c("02","03","04","05"),
    n = c(99,106,156,237)
  ) %>%
  mutate(Week = yearweek(paste0("2020 W",Week))) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Week)
out 
#> # A tsibble: 4 x 2 [1W]
#>       Week     n
#>     <week> <dbl>
#> 1 2020 W02    99
#> 2 2020 W03   106
#> 3 2020 W04   156
#> 4 2020 W05   237

out %>%
  model(ses = ETS(n ~ season("N"))) %>%
  forecast(h = "10 weeks") %>%
  autoplot(out)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The model is equivalent to the one you are fitting with `HoltWinters()`, although the parameter estimation in `ETS()` uses MLE rather than the mix of LS with ad hoc heuristic estimates that is used by `HoltWinters()`.

See [OTexts.com/fpp3](https://OTexts.com/fpp3) for a textbook on how to use these packages.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! The chart looks good. Am I correct that the forecast for February as well as future 95% certainty will be a maximum of about 300?

hw = HoltWinters(y, alpha=NULL, beta=TRUE, gamma=FALSE)

If I do my version (beta = TRUE) I get a forecast that goes far beyond 300.
Did I get something wrong?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Anha9q2JgYDshakFuSEzNFsG3Q827g?e=lycDlb.png

Comment: The code in your question has no trend, so it doesn't match the graph in your comment. In any case, I wouldn't trust any forecast built on four observations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob for your help. if I set beta=TRUE in my code, then I have a forecast. However, I suspect that this one is rising too steeply. But as you said, with only 4 observations it's difficult to make an accurate prediction.
What I didn't understand with your graph is how the forecast is expected for the next weeks. Is a maximum value around 300 to 95% expected?

Comment: The shaded regions are prediction intervals. If the forecast is to be believed (which it is not given only 4 observations), there is a 2.5% chance of it being above the upper limit.